# Threading help maybe?

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib

So I would need to make these two things run at the same time

```
    savedFile = open('Exchange_Rates' + time.strftime("_%d.%m.%Y.log"), 'w')
while spot < 60:
    savedFile.write(str(currencies.get_rate()) + ',' + str(spot) + '\n')
    savedFile.flush()
    spot += 1
    time.sleep(1)
savedFile.close()
```

and this

```
def animate(i):
    pullData = open('Exchangerates' + time.strftime('_%d.%m.%Y.log'), 'r').read()
    dataArray = pullData.split('\n')
    xar = []
    yar = []
    for eachLine in dataArray:
        if len(eachLine) > 1:
            x, y = eachLine.split(',')
            xar.append(int(x))
            yar.append(int(y))
     ax1.clear()
     ax1.plot(xar, yar)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

Do I need to use the threading module or how else would I go and do it. Or do I use something else, if so what?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you need the threading module. I would recomend you this article http://softwareramblings.com/2008/06/running-functions-as-threads-in-python.html

The simplest way:

```
 import thread

 def someFunc():
    print "someFunc was called"

thread.start_new_thread(someFunc, ())
```

The more advanced way:

```
import threading

t1 = threading.Thread(target=someFunc)
t1.start()
t1.join()
```